# Converting Integer to NSString is Computational Too Expensive

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode

I'm using a NSMutableDictionary as a Hash Table. I generate my hash keys by doing some integer operations, so the final generated hash key is an integer.

I know it's easy to convert the integer key to NSString in order to use it as a key for my NSMutableDictionary. I can do it by using [NSString stringWithFormat...];. But the problem is that the implicit conversion contained in that method (stringWithFormat...) is computational too expensive for what I'm doing. That single method slows down all my application.

*Do you know a work around for this problem?*

Like maybe using integers as keys for my hash table somehow? Or an eficient way to conver integers to NSStrings?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that you want to use a string, because you think, you have to. It is true that you cannot use scalar types like `NSInteger`, but you can use every object of a class that conforms to `NSCopying`.

Therefore you can convert the integer into a instance of `NSNumber` instead and use this as a key.

```
id value = …
NSInteger hash = …
NSDictionary *dictionary = …;
[dictionary setObject:… forKey:@(hash)];
…
value = [dictionary objectForKey:@(hash)];
```

I'm pretty sure that this is faster. (Internally there are some "dirty hacks" for making integral numbers fast.)

Additionally copying in the object into the `NSDictionary` might be slow. You can use a [`NSMapTable`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSMapTable_class/index.html), configured to no copying, instead

Edited to use NSDictionary's accessor methods.

> In general, a key can be any object (provided that it conforms to the
>   NSCopying protocol—see below), but note that when using key-value
>   coding the key must be a string (see Key-Value Coding Fundamentals).

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work. The app crashed when running that code. And it had this warning: "Incompatible pointer types 'NSNumber *' to parameter of type 'NSString *'".

Comment: Of course you have to adopt other parts of your code to use `NSNumber` instead of `NSString`.

Comment: BTW: You know that Cocoa collections uses heavily hash tables internally. So maybe you hash something that's hashed.

Comment: The crash and warning occurred when using the NSMutableDictionary methods "valueForKey:" and ""setValue:ForKey:. I passed them the @(NSInteger) as the input key as you told me to, but no success.

Comment: Oh, sorry, my fault. You should use `NSDictionary's` methods instead of KVC. Changed that in my answer.

Comment: Look at the edit. If you use KVC (`-setValue:forKey:`, `-valueForKey:`, …) you have to have a string key. But with `NSDictionary`'s `-objectForKey:` and `-setObject:forKey:` the key might be `id<NSCopying>`.

Comment: Thanks for the workaround. It works like a charm. I improved my code performance in about 300%... I also tried with the NSMapTable, buy the performance is the same than with the NSMutableDictionary... Thxs

Comment: You're welcome and interesting that `NSMapTable` did not give a change. (Probably because some `NSNumber` instances are treated as scalar.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
int a = 35;
NSString* string = [@(a) stringValue];
```